# Union по заранее неизвестному количеству таблиц

Tags: sql, postgresql

Есть несколько таблиц с названием вида: "data_01_23". Каждый месяц создается новая.
Необходимо получать некие агрегированные данные со всех.
Сейчас это реализовано как-то так:

```
select *
from data_01_23
union all
select *
from data_02_23
```

Из-за чего нужно каждый раз проверять какие таблицы существуют и менять запрос.
Возможно ли автоматизировать этот процесс не прибегая к пайплайну? Количество и название таблиц можно брать с Information_schema, но как это использовать кроме как прописать огромный case я не придумал.

Comment: *Возможно ли автоматизировать этот процесс не прибегая к пайплайну?* Изменить структуру БД. Перейти от отдельных таблиц к партиционированию.

Comment: Использовать [Dynamic SQL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ecpg-dynamic.html). Для упрощения получения нужных таблиц, помещать их в отдельную схему: [Schemas](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-schemas.html). / Но партицирование гораздо лучше! [Table Partitioning](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-partitioning.html)